# How to add custom html in django admin field?

Tags: django, django-admin

Basically, what I want to achieve is to have a media form that show an image  thumbnail after I choose the file in the add or edit interface. I try using this code but it returned in this error.

```
Unknown field(s) (admin_image) specified for ImageMedia. 
Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ImageMediaAdmin.
```

This is the model class:

```
class ImageMedia(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_media', blank=True)

    def admin_image(self):
        return '<img src="%s" height="300px"/>' % self.picture
    admin_image.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

This is the admin class

```
class ImageMediaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('caption', 'picture', 'admin_image')
    search_fields = ('caption', 'picture')
    fields = ('caption', 'picture', 'admin_image')

admin.site.register(ImageMedia, ImageMediaAdmin)
```

Comment: You need to remove it from `fields`, since its not a field but a function; that will get rid of the immediate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `ImageMediaAdmin` to specify `admin_image` as a `readonly_field`.

```
class ImageMediaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('caption', 'picture', 'admin_image')
    search_fields = ('caption', 'picture')
    fields = ('caption', 'picture', 'admin_image')
    readonly_fields = ['admin_image']
```

Comment: Its not a field, but a callable. You can't have a callable in the `fields` tuple.

Comment: That's what the ```readonly_fields``` is there to help with. I've used this before and it's worked.